# movie ticket booking in a particular row using array

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, multidimensional-array, collections

We have to check the seat availability and book two consecutive tickets in the same row.
    If tickets are not available or If two tickets booked from two different rows then we have to throw an exception (using arrays)
    Condition 1: if i select 7th and 8th seat, as it is from different row we are not supposed to allow them.
    Condition 2: if i enter the seat as 100 and 101, as the specified seats are not available , we are not supposed to book the seats.`

```
It would be great, if someone could help out on this,
```

package demo;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Newtable {

    public static void printRow(int[] row) {
        for (int i : row) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int twoDm[][] = new int[5][7];
        int i, j, k = 1, m = 2;
        int ab = 0;
        int firstticket;
        int secondticket;
        boolean firstTicketFlag = false;
        boolean secondTicketFlag = false;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                twoDm[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        }

        for (int[] row : twoDm) {
            printRow(row);
        }

        // this loop repeats the reserving process (and printing seats) 5 times
        for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {

            System.out.print("Enter the Seats number to reserve: ");
            firstticket = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            secondticket = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            firstTicketFlag = containsCheck(twoDm, firstticket);
            secondTicketFlag = containsCheck(twoDm, firstticket);

            if (firstTicketFlag && secondTicketFlag) {

                if (firstticket == (secondticket - 1)) {

                    k = 1;
                    m = 2;
                    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {

                            if (k == firstticket && m == secondticket) {
                                // here we check if the seat has already been
                                // reserved
                                ab = m - 1;
                                if (twoDm[i][j] == 0 && twoDm[i][j+1] == 0) {
                                    throw new Exception("That seat has already been reserved");
                                }
                                // if its not reserved then reserve it
                                else {
                                    //ab = m - 1;
                                    twoDm[i][j] = 0;
                                    twoDm[i][j+1] = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            k++;
                            m++;
                        }
                    }
                    // print updated array of seats
                    for (int[] row : twoDm) {
                        printRow(row);
                    }

                } else {
                    throw new Exception(" select two seats in the same row");
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter the available seat numbers");
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean containsCheck(int[][] twoDm, int ticket) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int[] a : twoDm) {
            if (a.equals(ticket)) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you have 5 rows of seats, with each row containing 7 seats?

Comment: What problems are you specificly facing? You've dumped the task and some code. Does the code work? What is the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secondTicketFlag is not checked correctly:

```
secondTicketFlag = containsCheck(twoDm, firstticket);
//should be
secondTicketFlag = containsCheck(twoDm, secondticket);
```

containsCheck needs another *for* loop to check the individual values of every seat inside the row (one dimensional array):

```
private static boolean containsCheck(int[][] twoDm, int ticket) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean flag = false;
// added another for loop, and changed "equals" to == since the values are int
        for (int[] oneDm : twoDm) {
            for (int individualSeat : oneDm) {
                if (individualSeat == ticket) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

And if the first seat OR the second seat is booked then you want to return error,

```
if (twoDm[i][j] == 0 && twoDm[i][j+1] == 0)
//should be 
if (twoDm[i][j] == 0 || twoDm[i][j+1] == 0)
```

Sorry for any formatting mistakes(first time commenting) and hopefully that solves the problem you had.

EDIT: You have various ways to check that the seats are on the same row, given the way you are putting the values of the seats, I would use the remainder (%) operator

If the first seat has a remainder different from 0 that means that the two seats are on the same row (the first seat must be between 1-6, 8-13, 15-20... it can't be a multiple of 7), you could also use the j value on the *for* loop. That's up to you. The way to check the remainder:

```
if(firstticket % 7 == 0){ System.out.println("The seats are not in the same row");}
```

Comment: I got your first two points clearly. Can u please explain me this once again if(firstticket % 7 == 0){ System.out.println("The seats are not in the same row");}

Comment: Can u please share me that logic to check if the seats are on the same row or not. @aLittleSalty. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: If your first seat is the number 7, 14, 21, 28 (multiples of 7), the second seat will always be on a different row(the next one).  To check if a number is multiple of 7 you have to check the remainder of the division (for example, the remainder of doing 15/7 is 1). To calculate the remainder in java we use the "%" operator instead of the "/".
21 / 7 = 3, but 21 % 7 = 0 (nothing left).